# ESP8266 sending data to web server

Tags: web, lua, embedded

I need to make an WEB based monitoring system using ESP8266, which could display the data. The system will have a user registration form, which should allow to display the data for a particular user. For this purpose I got a remote server (domain). Now I'm facing with some problems, how could I send data to this domain from the ESP? My ESP module uses NodeMCU firmware and I can program it using Lua. I read that there is HTTP GET and POST request methods and I unsuccessfully spent a few days trying to implement one of these methods... Maybe someone could put me on the road What should be the sequence of steps to start sending data to the external server? That would be a big step forward if I could send f.e. constant value variable.

Comment: Have you looked at the manual?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your NodeMCU is connected to a network and had internet access, you can just do

```
http.post(url, headers, body, callback)
```

and it should send a post request to the given URL. HTTPS also works here, but has limitations.

Note that you need to compile the firmware with the HTTP (and TLS if you want HTTPS) module(s) by uncommenting the corresponding line(s) in the `app/include/user_modules.h` file.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. So, this task cannot be completed just using only Lua scripts? I need to use HTTP client?  for example: https://github.com/Caerbannog/esphttpclient

Comment: not really; as I said, you can use the builtin module to make the HTTP request. All you need to do is to enable it when compiling the firmware and you can just call the `http.post` and `http.get` methods directly from Lua.